# How to record push open from Parse Push notification

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, react-native, parse-server

I am using Parse (parse 1.9.2) to send push notification to Android and IOS with React Native. However, even if I click on the notification and the app opened, Parse does not record this event. What do I have to do to record with Parse that this notification is opened. When I open `Past Push` on Parse dashboard, it always said that `N/A Notifications Opens`. Please help

[image]

Comment: Well, do you use a standard `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver ` or your own implementation?

Comment: Hi, the notification are received to your android device?

Comment: @RanHassid: yes I received the notification on my devices.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should add

```
ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);
```

to your onPushOpen implementation in your ParsePushBroadcastReceiver implementation.

Please refer to: http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseAnalytics.html#trackAppOpenedInBackground(android.content.Intent)

Comment: I am using React Native not android SDK though

Comment: Since you are using React Native, you could use the javascript api. 
You could try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27128048/how-to-track-app-open-in-parse-analytics-using-javascript